# Microsoft.Graph 4.0.0 Error in creating a list with columns: Error: A null value was found for the property named 'id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

After move to a new version of Microsoft.Graph 4.0.0. my list creation requests starts to fail with error in creation of ColumnDefinition object. If create a list without column - it works fine:

```
Error: Code: invalidRequest
Message: [list] A null value was found for the property named 'id', which has the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-08-05T07:46:29
    request-id: d1f5391d-38ad-4c8d-af12-0b6e10c1c750
    client-request-id: d1f5391d-38ad-4c8d-af12-0b6e10c1c750
ClientRequestId: d1f5391d-38ad-4c8d-af12-0b6e10c1c750
```

My columnt definition code:

```
        public static ColumnDefinition TextColumn(string columnName, bool isMultiText, bool isIndexed)
        {
            var text = new TextColumn();
            if (isMultiText)
            {
                text.AllowMultipleLines = true;
                text.TextType = "richText";
            }
            text.ODataType = "microsoft.graph.textColumn";
            return new ColumnDefinition
            {
                Name = columnName,
                DisplayName = columnName,
                Text = text,
                ReadOnly = false,
                Required = false,
                EnforceUniqueValues = false,
                Indexed = isIndexed,
                ODataType = "microsoft.graph.columnDefinition"
            };
        }
```

My list creation code:

```
        public static List NewLibrary(string name)
        {
            var Column1 = ColumnsBuilder.TextColumn("Column1", false, true);
            var Column2 = ColumnsBuilder.TextColumn("Column2", false, true);
            
            
            var listOfCols = new List<ColumnDefinition>() { Column1, Column2 };
            var columns = new ListColumnsCollectionPage();
            foreach (ColumnDefinition item in listOfCols)
            {
                columns.Add(item);
            }
            return new List()
            {
                DisplayName = name,
                Columns = columns,
                ListInfo = new ListInfo
                {
                    Template = "documentLibrary"
                }
            };
        }
```

And request itself:

```
            var library = ListsBuilder.NewLibrary(driveName);
            try
            {
                List result = await _client.Sites[siteId].Lists.Request().AddAsync(library);
                
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Error in Library creation:\nName: {0}\nError: {1}", driveName, ex.Message);
                throw e;
            }
```

The documentation is outdated.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

THe problem was in new JSON serializer (JSON.NET) in Microsoft Graph 4.0.0. IT didn't serialize correctly nested collections.
Fixed in 4.1.0